# Implementing a Scala trait by passing functions as arguments

Tags: scala

Say we have a Scala trait

```
trait Foo {
  def bar(baz: Qux): Quux
  def corge: Grault
}
```

and we want to implement it in such a way that the implementation of `bar()` can be handled by an anonymous function. We can do this:

```
class FooImpl1(_bar: (Qux) => Quux, val corge: Grault) extends Foo {
  override def bar(baz: Qux) = { _bar(baz) }
}
```

allowing, e.g.:

```
val foo: Foo = new FooImpl({ qux: Qux => qux.asQuux()}, someGrault)
```

But this seems unnecessarily verbose (and also introduces the dreaded, and clunky, leading underscore).

Naively, noting that `def corge` in `Foo` is implemented by `val corge` in `FooImpl1`, it seems it should be possible to do something like this:

```
class FooImpl2(val bar: (Qux) => Quux, val corge: Grault) extends Foo {}
```

But we can't, presumably because `Foo.bar` doesn't *return* a function, it *is* a function (or rather a method).

Is there anything cleaner than `FooImpl1` that we can do here?

Answer (score 1):

If you have control of the trait, you could try modifying it instead:

```
trait Foo {
  val bar: Function1[Qux, Quux]
  def corge: Grault
}
```

which makes your `FooImpl2` definition possible.  Here's an example from an Eclipse ScalaWorksheet:

```
package so

object ClassExperiment {
  type Qux = Int
  type Quux = Boolean
  type Grault = String

  trait Foo {
    val bar: Function1[Qux, Quux]
    def corge: Grault
  }

  class FooImpl2(val bar: (Qux) => Quux, val corge: Grault) extends Foo {
    def blue = bar( 9 )
  }

  val foo = new FooImpl2( { a: Qux => a == 4 }, new Grault("monkey") )
                                                  //> foo  : so.ClassExperiment.FooImpl2 = so.ClassExperiment$FooImpl2@68f
                                                  //| e748f

  foo.blue                                        //> res0: so.ClassExperiment.Quux = false
  foo.bar( 4 )                                    //> res1: so.ClassExperiment.Quux = true
  foo.bar( 7 )                                    //> res2: so.ClassExperiment.Quux = false
  foo.corge                                       //> res3: so.ClassExperiment.Grault = monkey
}
```

I left off the `Foo` type specifier when creating `foo` so I could show the call output to `blue`.

Comment: In the general case it's more likely that implementations are just going to implement the method.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this?

```
val foo = new Foo { 
   def bar(qux : Qux) = qux.asQuux 
   val corge = someGrault
}
```

It doesn't seem like defining a FooImpl class really buys you anything.

Comment: He wants to be able to specify the behaviour of `bar()` separately from the construction of the class

Comment: It's a toy example. IRL it's obviously not worth doing unless you have multiple implementations.